# Reconnect sessions when they have been closed due to inactive timeout

Tags: hibernate, jpa, timeout, c3p0

I’m using Hibernate + C3P0 reading an Oracle database in a Tomcat 9 environment. Is it possible to automatically reconnect jdbc sessions when they have been closed due to inactive timeout?. What parameters should be set to persistence.xml?

I've this parameters among others:

- property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300000"
- property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="120"

The error showed is:
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper ORA-02396: ha excedido el tiempo máximo de inactividad, vuelva a conectarse

I've an error in my application when navigator remains unatended for a while. Then I need restart my application for reconect to de database. I want to evit that.

Comment: It's better to make `hibernate.c3p0.timeout` — which maps to c3p0's `c3p0.maxIdleTime` short rather than long, so that Connections aren't held idle for so long. Try `hibernate.c3p0.timeout=300`, something like that. That should prevent timed-out Connections from existing in the pool, but in any case you can protect your app from seeing them with `c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true`.

Comment: Thanks, @steve. I've changed timeout to 300 and added hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout as true, but the problem remains.

Comment: You may want to check the c3p0 config in your logs, and make sure the config you expect is getting through. c3p0 Connection pools dump their config at INFO level on initialization. If `c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true` and you are still seeing these errors, I wonder whether your app doesn't hold Connections checked out for long enough to time out. You could try the two parameters described [here](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients) for an approach to chase that down.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my problem was that there were incompatibilities in the versions of the Hibernate and C3P0 jars. Thus, C3P0 did not start and therefore it was not useful to modify its parameterization. Changing the version, everything works ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm glad you've figured it out!